# Replacing values in SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I have a csv file and I imported it into SAS. The csv file looks like-

```
G0705595,236.05,20081031170000,23.76,1
G0705595,236.05,20081031180000,23.76,1
G0705595,236.05,20081031190000,23.76,1
G0705595,236.05,20081031200000,23.76,1
G0705595,236.05,20081031210000,23.76,1
G0705598,236.05,20081031200000,16.00,1
G0705598,236.05,20081031210000,13.00,1
```

I used thecode below to get these data into a sas data set-

```
%let flname1=C:\temp\data.csv;
%put &=flname1;
data new;
infile "&flname1" dsd dlm=',';
length x1 $8;
input x1-x5;
run;
```

The value in first column is either G0705595 or G0705598. All I am trying to do is to replace all G0705595 with G1000000 and all G0705598 with G2000000.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do it programmatically (i.e., is there some pattern here - like G1000000 is first ID, G2000000 is second ID, etc.) or is it just those two specifically replaced?

Comment: @Joe- Hi Joe! I just want those two specifically replaced. There is no pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asmi,
If you are just doing a basic replace, the code below should work.

```
data new;
   set new;
    if x1 = 'G0705595' then x1 = 'G1000000';
    else if x1 = 'G0705598' then x1  = 'G2000000' ;
run;
```

Comment: @Keni- Thanks a lot Keni! I am fairly new to SAS and everything is a hit and trial right now. I think I was missing the single quotes in my program. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Without the quotes (single or double) the values would look like variable names.  SAS would happily create variables G0705595 etc although you should have received a note in the log about the uninitialized variables.

Comment: @Tom-Yes that's what exactly happened and I didn't know how to fix it. Thank you for the explanation!